# Sending e-mail automaticly in VBA 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macro.
 I need excel to send email AUTOMATICALLY whenever the due date is approaching. (Example about 15 days before). I got so far to the point where the e-mail is sent to all individuals with no regard to the do-date or conditional formatting.

```
Dim myApp As Outlook.Application, mymail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim mydate1 As Date
        Dim mydate2 As Long
        Dim datetoday1 As Date
        Dim datetoday2 As Long

Dim x As Long
With Sheet1

         Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         For x = 2 To Lastrow

        mydate1 = Cells(x, 6).Value
        mydate2 = mydate1

Cells(x, 10).Value = mydate2

        datetoday1 = Date
        datetoday2 = datetoday1

Cells(x, 9).Value = datetoday2

        If mydate2 - datetoday2 >= 15 Then

End If

    'Cells(x, 8).Font.Bold = “Send”
    Cells(x, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Cells(x, 8).Font.ColorIndex = 1
    Cells(x, 8).Font.Bold = True
    Cells(x, 8).Value = datetoday2 - mydate2

        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem

        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
        Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        olEmail.To = Cells(, 5).Value

With olEmail

        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        '.Display
        .HTMLBody = "<h1>Hej </h1><br> Detta är ett mail som du ska läsa" & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
        .Subject = "Möte"
        .BCC = Cells(x, 5).Value

        '.send
End With

 Next
        Set myApp = Nothing
        Set mymail = Nothing
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a line where you're testing the difference between two dates:

```
If mydate2 - datetoday2 >= 15 Then
```

I'm going to assume that if that date succeeds then you want to send the email. (I hope I'm wrong about that assumption. A test for a specific number of days needs to be better than that. More below.) So you want your email sending code to be after the if..then line and before the End if. However, you immediately follow the if...then with the End If.

You need to put the end if lower down:

```
If mydate2 - datetoday2 >= 15 Then

    'Cells(x, 8).Font.Bold = “Send”
    Cells(x, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    ' Code missed out here for clarity & brevity.

    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        '.Display
        .HTMLBody = "<h1>Hej </h1><br> Detta är ett mail som du ska läsa" & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
        .Subject = "Möte"
        .BCC = Cells(x, 5).Value

        '.send
    End With

End If ' Here is the end if from above
Next
```

Going back to the actual test you need to make, you should use the DateDiff function:

```
Dim d1 As Date
Dim d2 As Date
Dim days As Long

d1 = CDate("1 Jan 2016")
d2 = CDate("16 Jan 2016")

days = DateDiff("d", d2, d1) ' days is -15
days = DateDiff("d", d1, d2) ' days is +15

If days = 15 Then

    ' send email code

End If
```

Cheers -

Comment: `mydate2 - datetoday2 >= 15` works fine.  Dates are stored as doubles with the integer value equal to the number of days, so if all you care about are days they can be added and subtracted like that. If anything, the OPs casts to Long are superfluous - they only discard the time value stored to the right of the decimal.

Comment: I know that. I wanted to introduce a useful function which also eliminates the decimals. With the date subtraction his test becomes >= 15 & < 16; with datediff it's = 15 which reads more naturally to me. Style is a personal thing :)

Comment: I'm assuming the `>` is there for a purpose - for example to account for deadlines that have been missed because the code hasn't been run daily. Like you say "style is a personal thing", but I generally find 1 line of code a lot clearer and more readable than 5 and a mathematical operator more readable than remembering the parameter order of a function call.

Comment: I was assuming he wanted to send the email on a particular number of days before whatever it is happens. That is 15 days before but not 14 and not 16. The code he has now will send it on every run until the event is < 15 days away.

Comment: *That* is the answer to the OP's question (assuming that his cell value match his variable declarations) - not the style of his code.

Comment: That and getting the end if in the right place. And DateDiff also answers the same question, I think, but I'm not going to argue about it. Cheers!